# Soap php Microsoft Dynamics crm online 2011

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, nusoap

i'm having errors using nusoap to talk to microsoft dynamics crm online 2011.
This is some debug info

```
 Error: wsdl error: Getting https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 - HTTP ERROR: no proper separation of headers and document

Debug

2013-02-22 09:13:58.670652 nusoap_client: ctor wsdl=wsdl timeout=0 response_timeout=30
endpoint=string(16) "organization.xml"
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676050 nusoap_client: will use lazy evaluation of wsdl from organization.xml
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676090 nusoap_client: setCredentials username=testserver2013.onmicrosoft.com\matthewhudghton authtype=ntlm certRequest=
array(0) {
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676141 nusoap_client: setUseCURL(1)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676169 nusoap_client: useHTTPPersistentConnection
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676367 nusoap_client: call: operation=Create, namespace=http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices, soapAction=http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Create, rpcParams=, style=rpc, use=encoded, endpointType=wsdl
params=string(223) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></soap:Envelope>"
headers=array(3) {
  ["SOAPAction"]=>
  string(56) "http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Create"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(23) "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  int(1095)
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676435 nusoap_client: instantiating wsdl class with doc: organization.xml
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676539 wsdl: ctor wsdl= timeout=0 response_timeout=30
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676578 wsdl: parse and process WSDL path=
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676632 wsdl: setCredentials username=testserver2013.onmicrosoft.com\matthewhudghton authtype=ntlm certRequest=
array(0) {
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676679 wsdl: parse and process WSDL path=organization.xml
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676713 wsdl: parse WSDL at path=organization.xml
2013-02-22 09:13:58.676785 wsdl: getting WSDL file organization.xml
2013-02-22 09:13:58.693021 wsdl: Parse WSDL
2013-02-22 09:13:58.708375 wsdl: parsing import http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services - https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 (1)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.708615 wsdl: current service: OrganizationService
2013-02-22 09:13:58.708834 wsdl: current port: CustomBinding_IOrganizationService
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709290 wsdl: Parsing WSDL done
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709414 wsdl: parse WSDL at path=https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709482 wsdl: getting WSDL http(s) URL https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709646 soap_transport_http: ctor url=https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 use_curl=1 curl_options:
array(0) {
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709750 soap_transport_http: parsed URL scheme = https
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709814 soap_transport_http: parsed URL host = testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709865 soap_transport_http: parsed URL path = /XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709916 soap_transport_http: parsed URL query = wsdl=wsdl0
2013-02-22 09:13:58.709984 soap_transport_http: set header Host: testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710126 soap_transport_http: set header User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710205 soap_transport_http: setCredentials username=testserver2013.onmicrosoft.com\matthewhudghton authtype=ntlm digestRequest=
array(0) {
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710270 soap_transport_http: certRequest=
array(0) {
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710334 soap_transport_http: Authorization header not set for ntlm
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710398 soap_transport_http: set header Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710452 soap_transport_http: set header Connection: close
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710512 soap_transport_http: entered send() with data of length: 0
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710583 soap_transport_http: connect connection_timeout 0, response_timeout 30, scheme https, host testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com, port 443
2013-02-22 09:13:58.710662 soap_transport_http: connect using cURL
2013-02-22 09:13:58.750685 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10002, value=
string(93) "https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com:443/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"
2013-02-22 09:13:58.750843 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=52, value=
int(1)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.750920 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=42, value=
int(1)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.750993 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=19913, value=
int(1)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751065 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=13, value=
int(30)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751133 soap_transport_http: set cURL SSL verify options
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751186 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=64, value=
int(0)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751255 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=81, value=
int(0)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751326 soap_transport_http: set cURL username/password
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751385 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10005, value=
string(62) "testserver2013.onmicrosoft.com\matthewhudghton:fakepassword"
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751519 soap_transport_http: set cURL for NTLM authentication
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751574 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=107, value=
int(8)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751644 soap_transport_http: cURL connection set up
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751721 soap_transport_http: HTTP request: GET /XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 HTTP/1.1
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751791 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Host: testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751845 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751897 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
2013-02-22 09:13:58.751950 soap_transport_http: HTTP header: Connection: close
2013-02-22 09:13:58.752017 soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header Host: testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com
2013-02-22 09:13:58.752091 soap_transport_http: Skip cURL header Connection: close
2013-02-22 09:13:58.752145 soap_transport_http: setCurlOption option=10023, value=
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)"
  [1]=>
  string(30) "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
}
2013-02-22 09:13:58.752243 soap_transport_http: set cURL HTTP headers
2013-02-22 09:13:58.752369 soap_transport_http: set cURL payload
2013-02-22 09:13:58.752444 soap_transport_http: send and receive with cURL
2013-02-22 09:14:09.725981 soap_transport_http: No cURL error, closing cURL
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726600 soap_transport_http: Found HTTP header to skip
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726673 soap_transport_http: Found HTTP header to skip
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726727 soap_transport_http: no proper separation of headers and document
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726758 soap_transport_http: end of send()
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726804 wsdl: Getting https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 - HTTP ERROR: no proper separation of headers and document
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726898 nusoap_client: checkWSDL
2013-02-22 09:14:09.726932 nusoap_client: got wsdl error: Getting https://testserver2013.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0 - HTTP ERROR: no proper separation of headers and document
string(0) ""
```

And this is my current code:

```
   <?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$login ='testserver2013.onmicrosoft.com\matthewhudghton'; // crm login name 
$pass ='fakepassword';
$useCURL = 1;

$client = new nusoap_client("organization.xml", 'wsdl');
$client->setCredentials($login, $pass, 'ntlm');
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
exit();
}
$client->setUseCurl($useCURL);
$client->useHTTPPersistentConnection();

// Prepare values for the new contact.
$firstname = "112";
$lastname = "123";
$donotbulkemail = "true";
$address1_stateorprovince = "MT";
$address1_postalcode = "99999";
$address1_line1 = "23 Market St.";
$address1_city = "Sammamish";

// This exact header was recieved from GenerateAuthenticationHeader() JScript function.
$authenticationHeader = '<soap:Header><CrmAuthenticationToken xmlns=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices“><AuthenticationType xmlns=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes“>1</AuthenticationType><OrganizationName xmlns=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes“>personal</OrganizationName><CallerId xmlns=“http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/CoreTypes“>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</CallerId></CrmAuthenticationToken></soap:Header>';

// Prepare the SOAP message.
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" .  $authenticationHeader . "<soap:Body><Create xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'><entity xsi:type='contact'><address1_city>" . $address1_city . "</address1_city>" .  "<address1_line1>" . $address1_line1 . "</address1_line1>" .  "<address1_postalcode>" . $address1_postalcode . "</address1_postalcode>" .  "<address1_stateorprovince>" . $address1_stateorprovince . "</address1_stateorprovince>" .  "<donotbulkemail>" . $donotbulkemail . "</donotbulkemail>" .  "<firstname>" . $firstname . "</firstname>" .  "<lastname>" . $lastname . "</lastname>" .  "</entity>" .  "</Create>" .  "</soap:Body>" .  "</soap:Envelope>";

$headers = array('SOAPAction' => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Create', 'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length' => strlen($xml));



$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' .
    '<soap:Envelope' .          
        ' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' .
        ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' .
        ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' .
    $soapHeader .
    $soapBody .
    '</soap:Envelope>';

//SOAP call
$result = $client->call('Create', $xml, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Create', $headers);


if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<p><b>Fault: ';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</b></p>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<p><b>Error: ' . $err . '</b></p>';
        echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        print_r($result);
    }
}

var_dump($client->response);    

?>
```

any ideas? Not sure what "HTTP ERROR: no proper separation of headers and document" but feel it may just be because itas failing to authenticate for some reason.
Is my username in the correct format?
Thanks

Comment: How does it differ from your question asked two days ago? It's [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987476/wsdl-error-no-proper-separation-of-headers-and-document). I haven't scrutinized both posts because they are a bit too heavy on my eyes but they seem very alike. (Also, the lack of replies might have to do with the format of the question. It might behoove you if you make it shorter and help others help you.)